# Merging PDF's That are remotely stored Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm trying to merge PDF's together that are stored on S3 and once merged, download them all.

```
$mergePDF = PdfMerger::init();

foreach($models as $model){

    if(!is_null($model->filename)){

        $mergePDF->addPDF(file_get_contents(Storage::disk('spaces')->url('invoices/'.$model->filename)), 'all');
    }
}

$mergePDF->merge();

$mergePDF->save('invoices.pdf', "download");
```

If I try:

```
$mergePDF->addPDF(file_get_contents(Storage::disk('spaces')->url('invoices/'.$model->filename)), 'all');
```

**Gives me error:** file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

Other options:

```
$mergePDF->addPDF(Storage::disk('spaces')->url('invoices/'.$model->filename), 'all');
```

**Gives me error:** Could not locate PDF on 'https://example.org/invoices/invoice_2021_105.pdf'
While the URL exists and is accessible from the browser.

I'm using the following package:

```
composer require daltcore/lara-pdf-merger
```

I can't seem to be able to find the answer on how to use this with a remote disk.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `file_get_contents`, use `Storage::get` - something like:

```
Storage::disk('spaces')->get('invoices/'.$model->filename)
```

Comment: Unfortuately that doesn't work and throws an error.     "message": "file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given",

Comment: A URL is not considered a path.